# unpin apps from taskbar and start menu using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, com

In Windows 11, using PowerShell, I am trying to unpin Microsoft Store from the taskbar and ESPN & Spotify from the start menu.

```
function unpin_taskbar([string]$appname) {
    ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() |
        Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | Where-Object{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from taskbar'} | ForEach-Object{$_.DoIt()}
}

function unpin_startmenu([string]$appname) {
    ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() |
        Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | Where-Object{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from Start'} | ForEach-Object{$_.DoIt()}
}

foreach ($taskbarapp in 'Microsoft Store') {
    Write-Host unpinning $taskbarapp
    unpin_taskbar("$taskbarapp")
}

foreach ($startmenuapp in 'ESPN', 'Spotify') {
    Write-Host unpinning $startmenuapp
    unpin_startmenu("$startmenuapp")
}
```

Microsoft Store is unpinned successfully, but the next two fail. This is the output.

```
unpinning Microsoft Store
unpinning ESPN
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\repo\general\rundeck\windows\unpin_windows_apps.ps1:7 char:5
+     ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
unpinning Spotify
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\repo\general\rundeck\windows\unpin_windows_apps.ps1:7 char:5
+     ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: That probably means that `((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $appname})` returns nothing for the concerned apps.

Comment: I can see that ESPN and Spotify exist on the start menu.

Comment: But do you see them in `(New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | %  { $_.Name }`?

Comment: I guess those apps aren't under the current user account but somewhere under the AllUsers account. Meaning this probably more a Windows/Com object issue rather than a PowerShell programming issue (added some tags to the question).

Comment: any suggestions on how to remove the apps?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking at something like this by any change?

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.StartMenu
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.StartMenu

Remove-StartAppsTaskbarPinned -AppName "Microsoft Store"
Remove-StartAppsStartMenuPinned -AppName "ESPN"
Remove-StartAppsStartMenuPinned -AppName "Spotify"
```

You will need to install the module "Microsoft.PowerShell.StartMenu", this is mandatory to run those commands.
You can look at the powershell gallery to find out more what this is about and how it works.

Comment: how do you install this module? The first command can't find it for installation, and I have psgallery and nuget package sources installed.

Comment: Oh no, you're right it doesn't exist anymore (or it changed name). I'll check it out later on and let you know if I'll find anything

Comment: @Minkulai Did you ever find anything about the module being renamed or replaced?